# Weisinger's thesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

I am currently reading Atkin and Li's paper on Twists of newforms and Atkin-Lehner pseudo eigenvalues and one of the references there is to Weisinger's thesis:

Weisinger J., Some results on classical Eisenstein series and modular forms over function fields. Harvard thesis. (1977)

Does anyone have a scan or digital copy of it? Or an alternative reference that treats Atkin-Lehner operators $W_Q$ acting on Eisenstein series? (I know how $W_N$ acts on level $N$ Eisenstein series)

Answer (score 11):

A scanned copy of the thesis is available [here](http://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/blinowit/other/WeisingerThesis.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190815123755/http://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/blinowit/other/WeisingerThesis.pdf)).

Comment: Great thank you! To be honest I didn't expect that such a scan exists and thought I'd just ask on the off-chance someone can help me.

Comment: A few years ago I wrote a paper generalizing Weisinger's thesis (the Eisenstein part) to Hilbert modular forms. I  scanned the thesis then. I've actually been asked for copies of the scan several times since.

Comment: @BenLinowitz, the link no longer seems to work.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, Sorry about that. I just updated the link.

Comment: @Ben, did you know that Jim Weisinger had been at the Ross program?